# SQL,ORACLE - Create a view and pass the user's grants in the select's

Tags: sql, database, oracle, view

The infra team asked to create the view script, but also asked to pass the user's permissions in the selects.

Create the script ok, but how can I pass the Grants to a certain user

exemple:

```
CREATE VIEW sup_orders AS
  SELECT suppliers.supplier_id, orders.quantity, orders.price
  FROM suppliers
  INNER JOIN orders
  ON suppliers.supplier_id = orders.supplier_id
  WHERE suppliers.supplier_name = 'Microsoft';
```

how could I configure the user's grants in select's for this view?

Comment: A view does not take parameters.

Comment: if the  infra team means have the View definition and the grants to the view in the same script file then you should be able to give them the View DDL and the Grants to the view as you will know who will be accessing the view.

Comment: In other words, include the GRANT SELECT ON SUP_ORDERS TO ... ; commands in your script, as separate commands. They won't be part of the actual select statement in the view.